# Tomcat 9 WebXMLParseException con Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, tomcat, java-8

He estado intentando migrar una aplicación de Tomcat 8.0.27 a Tomcat 9.0.12 para empezar a utilizar HTTPS/2. La aplicación tiene como framework Spring 5.0, estas son las librerías que estoy utilizando:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="5.0.1.RELEASE"/>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="5.0.1.RELEASE"/>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="5.0.1.RELEASE"/>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="5.0.1.RELEASE"/>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="5.0.1.RELEASE"/>
```

La cuestión es que al intentar desplegar la aplicación me da las siguientes excepciones:

```
26-Oct-2018 08:35:04.790 GRAVE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Error de evaluación (parse) en el archivo web.xml de la aplicación a [file:/D:/Users/str_jui/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CintraOnfit/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml]
 org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
    at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setProperty(Driver.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1439)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:354)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

26-Oct-2018 08:35:04.927 GRAVE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Error de evaluación (parse) en el archivo web.xml de la aplicación a [jar:file:/D:/Users/str_jui/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CintraOnfit/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml]
 org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: not supported setting property http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler
    at org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setProperty(Driver.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1439)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(FragmentJarScannerCallback.java:77)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1927)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:354)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

He estado revisando mi archivo web.xml y no encuentro el motivo por el que puede estar fallando. Este es mi archivo web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>openingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.str.cintra.services.OpeningServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>openingServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/openingServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe este error? En mi anterior versión de Tomcat la aplicación deplegaba sin problemas. Por si sirve de algo, estoy utilizando la librería Java EE7 Endorsed API y el JDK8.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te faltan jars de las bibliotecas de org.xml.sax en la carpeta lib

Comment: @abrahamhs Muchas gracias, he añadido esta dependencia en mi archivo ivy `<dependency org="sax" name="sax" rev="2.0.1"/>` y me sigue dando el mismo error. ¿Te refieres a esta librería o a otras?